# What is this creature?

Tags: species-identification

I found this small creature in my water bucket which i filled from my water tank. I would like to know what kind of creature I have found here.

*Features* which ought to help for identification:

- Size = 1 cm
- 2.Transparent or semi Transparent
- 4 thread like legs
- 6 tentacles
- 2 black dots possibly eyes
- It can swim
- Triangular tail (Fish Like)
- Found in Karachi City, Pakistan.

[image]

Comment: I think I see 6 legs in the picture. Could that be?

Comment: I looks a bit like a shrimp (Caridea)

Comment: The triangular "tail" is actually the tail fan made of five parts. The central part of it is the final segment of the body and either side is composed of the two parts of a modified leg. Were you to investigate it more closely you'd thus discover it is not at all "fish like"

Comment: It looks very similar to the grey shrimps that can be catched on sandy beaches of Normandy (on the English Channel).

Answer (score 2):

It looks very similar to freshwater shrimp from [this](http://ecolinc.vic.edu.au/sites/default/files/uploaded_files/discovering_wetlands/gallery/view/116-981.html) site:

[image]